# looping through a folder and pulling excel files data into a main sheet and saving a copy after each output is completed

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have written a code in VBA to open certain sheets copy the worksheet data and the  paste the output into another sheet.

I have two questions, the current way I have done this is by writing the excel names in each bit of the code, this would be okay for a few workbooks but there are currently over 50 and the code would be ridiculously long. I was wondering whether there was a way to go through the folder containing the excel files and go through the list until completed.

```
Sub Openworkbook()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

'first worksheet to copy and paste

Workbooks.Open "C:\"

Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Isabella.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Testcode1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
  wsCopy.Range("A1:E86" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)

Workbooks("Isabella.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True

'Second worksheet to copy and paste

Workbooks.Open "C:\"

Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Jacob.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("Testcode1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
  wsCopy.Range("A1:E86" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)

Workbooks("Jacob.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True


End Sub
```

Thank you so much for your help.

*********************************UPDATE******************************************

I have rewritten the code below, if you need any help then please let me know and I will do my best to help you.

Comment: You need a for-next loop, plenty of examples online of looping through worksheets in a workbook.

Comment: Hi @SJR, there is only a single worksheet per workbook, there is over 50 workbooks I would need to open and close - Just read it was my mistake I put worksheets instead of workbooks.

Comment: what  should _"the file containing the excel files"_ actually mean?

Comment: Sorry @HTH "through the folder containing the excel files"

Comment: OK, there are also plenty of examples online of how to loop through workbooks in a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going back, getting some sleep and starting the code from scratch and below is what I came up with. Hope this helps

```
Sub RunIt()
Dim InputBook As Workbook
Dim OutputBook As Workbook
Dim DirFolder As String
Dim DirSel As String
Dim DirFile As String
Dim FileString As String
Dim InputArray As Variant
Dim LastLine As Long
Dim OutputName As String

Set OutputBook = ThisWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Choose folder and file type (*.* for all files, I have used csv).

DirFolder = "G:\"
DirSel = "*.csv*"
'File output destination
DirOut = "C:\"

' This loops through all the files in the folder above:

    DirFile = Dir(DirFolder & DirSel)
    Do While Len(DirFile) > 0
        FileString = DirFolder & DirFile

        ' I've put in a condition here to pick up only the correct file:
        If Left(DirFile, 5) = "02008" Then
            OutputName = Replace(DirFile, ".csv", "")

            ' Open the file
            Set InputBook = Workbooks.Open(FileString)
              ' Measure the number of rows:
            LastLine = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(InputBook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A"), ">""") + 1
                'Put the data into an array:
            InputArray = InputBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:L" & LastLine)
               ' Clear out the Lookup tab
            OutputBook.Sheets("Lookup").Range("A1:L1000").ClearContents
               ' Put the array data in:
            OutputBook.Sheets("Lookup").Range("A1:L" & LastLine) = InputArray
               ' Save a copy of the IBS_v022 file
            OutputBook.SaveCopyAs DirOut & "IBS Output " & OutputName & ".xlsm"

            InputBook.Close

        End If


        DirFile = Dir
    Loop


Set InputBook = Nothing
Set OutputBook = Nothing

MsgBox ("Complete")

End Sub
    enter code here
```

Comment: as they say: "you can't buy class"

Answer (score 0):

here's a help in hand in that I give a code and a pseudocode

the code

```
Sub CopyAndPaste(fullPath As String, wsDest As Worksheet)
    With Workbooks.Open(fullPath)
        With .Worksheets("Sheet2")
            .Range("A1:E" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

which is the sub to be called at every iteration of the pseudocode

the pseudocode

```
Sub Openworkbook()

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Testcode1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim fullPath As String

    for each ... 'code to loop through a folder files
        fullPath = ' extract the full path of current file
        CopyAndPaste fullPath, wsDest
    Next
    '
End Sub
```

so you only need to write the "real" code to loop through a folder files, which you can find plenty of in the net (and in SO mostly)